# How to expire non-used (at all) sessions sooner?

Tags: php, session

I have a webpage that creates a PHP session for each request - if it doesn't already exist.

In case of some robots, the session ID never gets passed back to the server with a next request. So, these sessions are useless, and they pile up fast as the robot is making many requests in a quick succession.

Is there a way to clean up such sessions? Or configure them a different "session.gc_maxlifetime"? So, if a normal user opens a page, gets a session ID and then passes it back with the next request, we apply the normal (longer) expiry time. But if the session ID is not used (passed with another request back) at all, we apply some shorter expiry time, say 1 min.

Comment: No, not really. You don't have a way of knowing what the client does with the session in advance.

Comment: "and they pile up" - Are you running into disk or storage issues?

Comment: "I have a webpage that creates a PHP session for each request" - If the bots are non-malicious, they should hopefully be identifiable with a common-enough pattern that you can just not give them a session, unless that's 100% needed for the rest of the site. If they are malicious, I'd solve this in front of the web application, at the infrastructure/firewall level.

Comment: 1/2 You could set the `gc_maxlifetime` to the lower value and keep updating the session with `$_SESSION['active'] = time()` or something. Depending on the backend (including the builtin `mod_mm` and `mod_files` backends) and setup (`sessionclean`) cleanup should honor this lower lifetime, but with legitimate clients the session will stay active as they're updated and not considered garbage.

Comment: 2/2 This will not work if you want to assign logged in users with a longer session (Remember me) functionality, if you want this dynamic behavior you can implement your own handler which has its own GC: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php

Comment: Is there a demonstrable _problem_ with these extra session files? Or did you simply look at the session storage dir and go "wow that's a lot"?

Comment: And @Sammitch, no, I was not running in any actual problems, I just thought "wow, that's a lot!". :) There are tens of thousands of these files, and I just thought that the majority of them are probably pointless and may cause problems by careless or malicious bots. Normally, browsers will reply with the session immediately in the following CSS and JS requests (although PHP won't see them). Maybe some specific AJAX check then. As otherwise it's a completely wasted session.

Comment: @soulseekah Yes, my idea was to allow for longer sessions once the browser has replied with the session ID at least once. Much longer than the initial short expiry duration. 1min vs 1 hour, for example. OK, so there is a way to manually do this with session handler. I'll keep that in mind.